# Ancestry Gem subtree errors (undefined method & object rendering)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I am very new to Ruby, so I might just be missing a simple thing here.

I am using the rails Ancestry gem to produce JSON output for an API I'm writing. Here is the controller:

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id]).subtree

        render json: @vendor, status: 200
    end
end
```

This produces the correct output showing the ID, vendor, ancestry etc.

However when I add `.arrange`, as such:

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id]).subtree.arrange

        render json: @vendor, status: 200
    end
end
```

The output I get is:

```
{"#\u003CVendor:0x4b9e628\u003E":
{"#\u003CVendor:0x4b9e3e8\u003E":
{},
"#\u003CVendor:0x4b9e1f0\u003E":
{}}}
```

which looks like memory locations for the objects. What fundamental thing am I missing to get this to actually output the objects in an arranged form?

I've also tried using `arrange_serializable` instead of `arrange`, this gives me a

`undefined method 'arrange_serializable' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Vendor:0x4b9b910>`

error

Comment: Use `arrange_serializable` instead of `arrange`.

Comment: @AlexPeachey: tried it. I get an error. Please see edit.

Comment: Did you actually get the ancestry-ness working on the ember side? I'm working on the same thing, but running into troubles even with some good-looking JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474369/error-in-parent-child-relationships-in-ember?noredirect=1#comment37893260_24474369

Comment: I'd never seen your "render" line anywhere so tried it in my code and got an error: "You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template, :inline, :file, :plain, :text or :body option." While that is not helpful, it would be helpful to (a) know what version of Rails you are using and (b) understand what you're trying to achieve. You say yourself that your original code produces the correct output. FWIW, I use "<%= @vendor.arrange_serializable.to_json %>" and that works for me at the moment.