# Error in parent/child relationships in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ancestry

I'm using Ember 1.5, Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.7 and the ancestry gem.

I have a model with a `parent` and `ancestors`, but any model entries that have a `parent` or `ancestor` get this weird error and fail.

Error:

```
Ember Inspector ($E):  Error: No model was found for 'ancestor'
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember.js?body=1:911:19)
    at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9808:33)
    at JSONSerializer.extend.extractSingle (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:3021:28)
    at superWrapper [as extractSingle] (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember.js?body=1:1293:16)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extractFind (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2483:21)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2368:37)
    at http://localhost:8080/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:10340:34
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember.js?body=1:10014:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:8080/assets/ember.js?body=1:9684:9) VM6302:164
```

I've commented out a bunch of code looking for anywhere I'm calling for an `ancestor` but I can't find it.

*Below is the code I've currently got in place that is still throwing this error.*

```
#models/dream_symbol.js.coffee
attr = DS.attr
App.DreamSymbol = DS.Model.extend
  description:  attr 'string'
  image:        attr 'string'
  name:         attr 'string'
  parent_id:    attr 'number'
  path:         attr 'string'
  rails_id:     attr 'number'
  thumbnail:    attr 'string'

  user:         DS.belongsTo 'user'

  parent:       DS.belongsTo('dream_symbol',
    inverse: 'children'
    embedded: 'always'
  )
#  ancestors:      DS.hasMany('dream_symbol',
#    inverse: 'children'
#    embedded: 'always'
#  )
  children:     DS.hasMany('dream_symbol',
    inverse: 'parent'
    embedded: 'always'
  )
  siblings:     DS.hasMany('dream_symbol',
    inverse: 'siblings'
    embedded: 'always'
  )
  interpretations:     DS.hasMany('interpretation',
    embedded: 'always'
  )

  serialize: ->
    @getProperties [ 'guid', 'image', 'name', 'description', 'parent', 'children', 'siblings', 'parent_id', 'interpretations', 'path', 'rails_id' ]
```

I commented out and removed any references to `ancestor` in the above code.
Below is my routes, and I've completely commented out my `DreamSymbolShowController`.

```
# Show Route
App.DreamSymbolsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    @store.find 'dream_symbol', params.id

  actions:
    edit: ->
      @transitionTo 'dream_symbols.edit', @currentModel

    new: (params)->
      referrer = @currentModel.get 'id'
      parent_id = ( if params then params.id else null )
      @transitionTo('dream_symbols.new').then (newRoute)->
        newRoute.controller.set 'previous', referrer
        newRoute.currentModel.set 'parent_id', parent_id
```

DOes anyone have a thought on what to try to look into why I'd be getting errors on child pages but not parent pages, and what I can do about it?

### UPDATE:

Here's my current JSON response I'm getting:

```
{
  ancestors: [
    {
      id: "body-parts",
      name: "Body Parts",
      description: "Qoop",
      user_id: null,
      image: null,
      thumbnail: null,
      rails_id: 24
    }
  ],
  children: [ ],
  parent: [
    {
      id: "body-parts",
      name: "Body Parts",
      description: "Qoop",
      user_id: null,
      image: null,
      thumbnail: null,
      rails_id: 24
    }
  ],
  siblings: [
    {
      id: "root-level-child",
      name: "Hand",
      description: "ff",
      user_id: null,
      image: null,
      thumbnail: null,
      rails_id: 25
    }
  ],
  dream_symbol: {
    id: "root-level-child",
    description: "ff",
    image: null,
    name: "Hand",
    parent_rails_id: 24,
    rails_id: 25,
    thumbnail: null,
    user_id: null,
    ancestors: [
      "body-parts"
    ],
    children: [ ],
    parent: "body-parts",
    siblings: [
      "root-level-child"
    ]
  }
}
```

There's something I need to change with the `belongsTo` and `hasMany` setups. Kind of stumped over here.

Comment: I've commented out any code in the views except for a text line saying `Woot`. So there shouldn't be any calls for an `ancestor` object in the views.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON payload structure matches the structure that Ember Data is expecting? You may need to look at [customizing your adapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/) if you do not have control of the JSON payload coming from the server.

Comment: I have control over the JSON payload and am just tinkering with that right now. I just tried removing all the side-loaded data and returns functionality to the show page. So it must be something in the serializer, or the `hasMany` setup.

Comment: I had someone on IRC that the JSON should be returned with the actual model name. So `dream_symbols` rather than `ancestors`. Hasn't worked for me yet.

Comment: Just found this _probably_ related SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727512/self-join-with-ember-data